# Error: Could not find or load main class - Java cygwin

Tags: java, linux, cygwin, classpath

Using cygwin on windows 7.

To compile all my files I do:

```
javac -cp ./antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

which works fine. Then I try

```
java -cp .:./antlr-3.2.jar Interpreter
```

where interpreter is a `.java` file that I know is in the current directory. I thought adding `.` to the classpath would fix my problem but I am still getting

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Interpreter
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even though you are running under cygwin, the java.exe is still a windows program.

It needs `;` as class path delimiter. Try ,

```
java -cp ".;./antlr-3.2.jar" Interpreter
```

or

```
java -cp .\;./antlr-3.2.jar Interpreter
```

You need to escape or quote the classpath correctly so that it is not interpreted by shell.

Comment: Offtopic : Generally try to use some kind of build tools to do that build (gradle/ant etc are easy to start).  In you case the source code area is polluted with many .class files.